# VBA insert vbNewLine in the first blank character

Tags: vba

I need to insert a vbNewLine in a cell string value after the first blank character encountered after the 50 first characters?

For example:
"At company employees with the right skills have good prospects to be promoted then a relevant position becomes available" should become

"At company employees with the right skills *(vbNewLine)*
 have good prospects to be promoted then a relevant position becomes available"

Comment: Note that your "should become" is incorrect. The new line is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Replace function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt3szac5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) can start at a certain point and replace a single occurrance of a character using parameters that are usually left to defaults.

```
Dim str As String, i As Long
i = 50
str = "At company employees with the right skills have good prospects to be promoted then a relevant position becomes available"
str = Left(str, i - 1) & Replace(str, Chr(32), Chr(10), _
                                 Start:=i, Count:=1)
Debug.Print str
```

Use 50 as the starting point, the result I receive is,

```
At company employees with the right skills have good
prospects to be promoted then a relevant position becomes available
```

Answer (score 3):

Since your question is so nicely posed, here's a solution

```
Sub solution()

    Dim test As String
    Dim pos As Integer

    test = "At company employees with the right skills have good prospects to be promoted then a relevant position becomes available"

    pos = InStr(51, test, " ") 'search for a space on or after the 51st character

    If (pos >= 51) Then
        'found a space
        test = Left(test, pos) & vbNewLine & Mid(test, pos + 1) 'miss out that space
    End If

    Debug.Print test


End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `If (pos >= 51) Then` in case the 51st character is a space?

Comment: #DevProbs - Everyone counts from 1, we count from 0!